# Change the text color of a button with an option

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, html-select

I have some issues with options, can someone help me ? 
I have a button with id="colorButton" but I don't know how to change his color with options.

```html
<form>
<select id="colorSelect">
<option selected disabled>Text-Align : </option>
<option value="1">Red</option>
<option value="2">Blue</option>
<option value="3">Green</option>
</select>
</form>
```

It can be a javascript answer, jquery... please :( 
I have this in script :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  if ($("#colorSelect").click().val("1"){
   $("#testButton").css("color", "red");
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But ofc it don't work :(

Comment: `if ($("#colorSelect").click().val("1")){`

Comment: Don't use an if statement, bind a change handler to your option element. Also, you said that your button has the ID of `colorButton` but in your example you used `$("#testButton")`

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains lots bugs, you just need to bind a change event handler and set color based on selected option.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#colorSelect").change(function() {
    $("#testButton").css("color", $(':selected', this).text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select id="colorSelect">  
<option selected disabled>Text-Align : </option>
<option value="1">Red</option>
<option value="2">Blue</option>
<option value="3">Green</option>
</select>
</form>

<div id="testButton">button</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind to the change event of the select like:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#colorSelect").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 1) $("#testButton").css("color", "red");
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select id="colorSelect">
<option selected disabled>Text-Align : </option>
<option value="1">Red</option>
<option value="2">Blue</option>
<option value="3">Green</option>
</select>
</form>
<button id="testButton">button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Everyone is focusing on making your `code` functional. I put the effort to solve your problem in different way.

Each `option` has `data-color` attribute. When you change dropdown then selected option's `data-color` value get picked and changes color. In this way, you don't need multiple if-else.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#colorSelect').on('change', function(){
    var color = $(this).find(':selected').data('color');
    $("#testButton").css("color", color);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select id="colorSelect">
    <option selected disabled>Text-Align : </option>
    <option data-color='red'>Red</option>
    <option data-color='blue'>Blue</option>
    <option data-color='green'>Green</option>
  </select>
  <button id="testButton">button</button>
</form>
```